# simple form search

Tags: search

I have created a simple_form for a search bar in a sidebar. I can view it in the debugger and it highlights when I submit but nothing happens. I have added a result_page and a no_result_page but nothing occurs. I would expect to hit one of those pages upon submission but nothing happens?

```
{exp:search:simple_form 
            channel="articles" 
            result_page="search/results" 
            no_result_page="articles"
            results="10" 
            show_future_entries="no" 
            status="open" 
            where="any"
            }
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Any ideas why its not submitting anywhere? Ive checked and the search module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a standard error message something like "You did not submit a search term"??

This is the first step, your search keywords field needs to be named and ID'd `keywords` so :

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Search">
```

Once I do this my search form submits without errors, in fact as I have no articles channel it forwards me to `/articles/[SEARCHKEY]` i.e. no results...

My recommendation is to start with the documented form and alter it to your needs, testing results/no results as you go : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/simple.html

**Edit** : Additionally

I note your no results path is just `/articles`, note that simple search will append the search key to your URL, so on no results will go to `/articles/SOMEALPHANUMSTRING`. I assume you have a Template group called "articles" however wit hthe presence of the search key this will casue EE to look for a template called whatever the search key is. To get around this, make sure you set up your index template with the route path of `articles/{searchkey}` or similar, this will allow the search key to pass through.

If you use a scheme like `articles/url_title` to also display individual articles, on this single view template set your route to `articles/{article_url_title}` and make sure this route happens before your article listing /no results route in the route manager.

Answer (score 0):

Your search field needs naming "keywords":

```
<input type="search" name="keywords" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Search">
```

Try that...